How does knowing the sign of the population correlation affect the sufficiency of its statistic?
As noted here, the sufficient statistic for the correlation under bivariate normality is Pearson's $r$, the maximum likelihood estimate of $\rho$. I suppose, however, this does not guarantee that $r$ will be sufficient when one knows the sign of $\rho$, i.e., $\rho \geq 0$ or $\rho \leq 0$. In that case, but still under bivariate normality, is $r$ in fact still sufficient? Say, after truncating at 0? If not, does a sufficient statistic exist?

A fast and general answer. Let us first remember the definition of sufficiency, here I take it from Bickel & Doksum: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a parametric family of distributions, parameterized by $\theta \in \Theta$. Then $T(X)$ is called sufficient for $\mathcal{P}$ (or for $\theta$) if the conditional distribution of $X$ given $T(X)=t$ does not involve $\theta$.
In your case the parameter space for $\rho$ is $[-1, 1]$. If any statistic is sufficient for $\rho$ with that parameter space, it will continue to be sufficient for a reduced parameter space, like $[0,1]$. If the conditional distribution of the data given some statistic does not involve $\rho$, when considering the full space, restrictions  on the parameter space cannot induce dependence on $\rho$!
This is very general, and have nothing in particular to do with normal distributions or correlations, but is a general mathematical fact.

Thank you! Your answer holds for my question as stated, but I think it's phrased too generally. Suppose, contrary to my question, parameter sign is not known a priori but is conditional on on some sample-specific (ancillary) quantity. Then the ancillary statistic would fully disclose whether the parameter space is $[-1,0]$ or $[0,1]$. In that case, the sample is correlated with the parameter even conditional on $r$, and the ancillary statistic is required for sufficiency. So, in general, the statement "restrictions on the parameter space cannot induce dependence on $ρ$" does not hold.
